# ¿Que es el lenguaje Natural Adabas?

Tags: base-de-datos

Alguno de ustedes tendrá información de este lenguaje o me podrían brindar información para aprender mas sobre este lenguaje de programación

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola Yonatan. Este sitio no sustituye a un buscador web. Has de investigar por tu cuenta. Si durante una implementacion o uso tienes problemas concretos, pregutna aqui siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adabas parace ser la base de datos (con sus programas/scripts para arrancarla, hacer copias de seguridad y todo lo que se suele hacer con las bases de datos) y Natural, un lenguaje que se emplea para manejar los datos que contiene. Está orientado a grandes, inmensas BBDD, que no pueden permitirse estar inactivas o con el sistema caido (banca, Administración pública, etc) y que necesitan de un tiempo de respuesta mínimo con miles de usuarios conectados a la vez. 
Ambos llevan ya mucho tiempo en el mercado, pero algunas empresas aún se esmeran en usarle.
Te dejo un pdf que encontré por ahi.
[Natural Essentianls](http://www.spsimpson.com/nat-u/NATURAL%20Essentials.pdf)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte Saludos

Comment: Hola Mefit, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y así ganar tu primera medalla). También lee [answer] para encontrar consejos sobre cómo responder. Un saludo.